# Find mongoDB document with known child object value and dynamic parent

Tags: mongodb

We have data stored in mongodb by country code. Our document will look like the following,

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d82009cddf8d111b0f5c0f9"),
    "title" : "Keystone Korner",
    "CA" : {
        "dlp" : 21.99,
        "dlpCurrencyCode" : "CAD",
        "sales" : {
            "changeProceedsPriorDay" : 0.0,
            "changeUnitsPriorDay" : 0,
            "consumerPriceCurrencyCode" : null,
            "last30Proceeds" : 0.0,
            "last30Units" : 0,
            "last365Proceeds" : 4.22,
            "last365Units" : 4,
            "last60Proceeds" : 0.0,
            "last60Units" : 0,
            "last7Proceeds" : 0.0,
            "last7Units" : 0,
            "last90Proceeds" : 0.0,
            "last90Units" : 0,
            "lastAvgSalesPrice" : 0.0,
            "lastAvgSalesPricePrior" : 0.0,
            "lastProceeds" : 0.0,
            "lastProceedsPct" : 0.0,
            "lastProceedsPrior" : 0.0,
            "lastSalesDate" : "2021-08-23",
            "lastUnits" : 0,
            "lastUnitsPct" : 0.0,
            "lastUnitsPrior" : 0
        }
    },
    "US" : {
        "dlp" : 17.99,
        "dlpCurrencyCode" : "USD",
        "sales" : {
            "changeProceedsPriorDay" : 0.0,
            "changeUnitsPriorDay" : 0,
            "consumerPriceCurrencyCode" : null,
            "last30Proceeds" : 4.18,
            "last30Units" : 2,
            "last365Proceeds" : 51.66,
            "last365Units" : 19,
            "last60Proceeds" : 4.18,
            "last60Units" : 2,
            "last7Proceeds" : 0.0,
            "last7Units" : 0,
            "last90Proceeds" : 7.37,
            "last90Units" : 4,
            "lastAvgSalesPrice" : 0.0,
            "lastAvgSalesPricePrior" : 0.0,
            "lastProceeds" : 0.0,
            "lastProceedsPct" : 0.0,
            "lastProceedsPrior" : 0.0,
            "lastSalesDate" : "2021-08-25",
            "lastUnits" : 0,
            "lastUnitsPct" : 0.0,
            "lastUnitsPrior" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

I have provided only few country listings here but each document can contain almost 80-100 different country listings.

Our requirement is to identify the most recent `lastSalesDate` from `sales` parent under each country. So if we are able to list all `lastSalesDate` we may be able to sort and limit it by 1

How do we achieve this without knowing parents (Country codes like US, CA, GB, etc..)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$project` to show required fields
- `$objectToArray` to convert `$$ROOT` root document to an key-value format array of objects
- `$filter` to iterate loop of above root converted array and filter country object by checking `sales` property is `object`
- `$sort` by `lastSalesDate` in descending order
- `$limit` to get single and recent document
- `$let` to declare an inline variable for finding a maximum date from `lastSalesDate`
- `$max` to get maximum date from `lastSalesDate`
- `$indexOfArray` to get array index position from list of all country `lastSalesDate`
- `$arrayElemAt` to get recent country by above returned index position

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      title: 1,
      country: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
          cond: { $eq: [{ $type: "$$this.v.sales" }, "object"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "country.v.sales.lastSalesDate": -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 },
  {
    $addFields: {
      country: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            max: { $max: "$country.v.sales.lastSalesDate" }
          },
          in: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$country",
              { $indexOfArray: ["$country.v.sales.lastSalesDate", "$$max"] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m-nBWWrL6yD)

Result would be:

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("5d82009cddf8d111b0f5c0f9"),
    "country": {
      "k": "US",
      "v": {
        "dlp": 17.99,
        "dlpCurrencyCode": "USD",
        "sales": {
          "changeProceedsPriorDay": 0,
          "changeUnitsPriorDay": 0,
          "consumerPriceCurrencyCode": null,
          "last30Proceeds": 4.18,
          "last30Units": 2,
          "last365Proceeds": 51.66,
          "last365Units": 19,
          "last60Proceeds": 4.18,
          "last60Units": 2,
          "last7Proceeds": 0,
          "last7Units": 0,
          "last90Proceeds": 7.37,
          "last90Units": 4,
          "lastAvgSalesPrice": 0,
          "lastAvgSalesPricePrior": 0,
          "lastProceeds": 0,
          "lastProceedsPct": 0,
          "lastProceedsPrior": 0,
          "lastSalesDate": "2021-08-25",
          "lastUnits": 0,
          "lastUnitsPct": 0,
          "lastUnitsPrior": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "title": "Keystone Korner"
}]
```

Comment: One last question, based on above we will get max lastSalesDate ... Now if we need to pull all the document where it is >= max(lastSalesDate), do we need separate query ? If yes, how does it look like

Comment: You need to do new query, check [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EfITsMgUpUA)

Answer (score 1):

this aggregation

```
[
    {
        '$project': {
            't': {
                '$objectToArray': '$$ROOT'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'g': {
                '$map': {
                    'input': {
                        '$filter': {
                            'input': '$t', 
                            'as': 'tt', 
                            'cond': {
                                '$and': [
                                    {
                                        '$ne': [
                                            '$$tt.k', '_id'
                                        ]
                                    }, {
                                        '$ne': [
                                            '$$tt.k', 'title'
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    'as': 'featuresF', 
                    'in': {
                        'countyCode': '$$featuresF.k', 
                        'lastSale': '$$featuresF.v.sales.lastSalesDate'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

returns out put like

this :

```
{
_id:"12313131313131313",
[{
countyCode:"US",
lastSale:"2021-08-25"
},
{
countyCode:"CA",
lastSale:"2021-08-23"
}]
}
```

so if you want something else this, please provide some sample preferred output ,
after this stage we could query or sort or do etc with this data

Comment: We wanted to latest sale date. So result of query needs to return us only one data which contains lastSale: "2021-08-25" from above result